# How do I get autocomplete in VS Code for the mysql npm package?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, web, module, autocomplete

The general autocompletion works fine however I installed the `mysql` pacakge and when I write `mysql.` I don't get any suggestions other than the words already present in the current file. I checked the same thing in Neovim to make sure its not just a JavaScript thing but it works fine there. Is there any way I can enable such suggestions?

Comment: You can trigger IntelliSense in any editor window by typing Ctrl+Space or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in JavaScript).

Comment: @Shachar297 yes i do get suggestions however as mentioned its only words already present in the file and not the functions available in the installed mysql module which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql package doesn't bundle types. Types are available for it through [the Definitely Typed project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/) (you can tell because of the) [image] icon on [its npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). Install that with `npm install -D '@types/mysql'`. Then it should work. I presume you're doing an import like this?: `import * as mysql from "mysql";`.